Animation where people are divided over numbers or letters
I'm looking for a particular movie which was about numbers vs letters where the supporting characters are either for letters or numbers and the boy hero in the movie learns to use both to defeat the villain. The movie teaches children a bit about infinity. I watched it a lot around 6 and 7, wanted to find it for the kids. But the title seems to be very obscure. It was released in the 1980s or late 1970s. I probably first watched it around 1987-89, rented from local video store.
In one scene the villain challenges the hero to pick a number larger than the villains but he must choose first, the hero thinks and chooses 1 plus the any number the villain chooses.

This sounds like The Phantom Tollbooth - which is from 1970, but the description is very close to the action in the movie.  A better description can be found on wikipedia.
It is about a boy who goes into a magic world, with the cities of Digitopolis and Dictionopolis are ruled by (I believe) two brothers who believe that either Numbers or Letters are best.
The Phantom Tollbooth was originally a book by Norman Juster (which I read in my childhood and still own a copy of!).
Summary of the film version:

Milo, a bored, lonely boy who lives in a San Francisco apartment block
  all by himself, is surprised by the sudden arrival of a large,
  gift-wrapped package. Inside is a tollbooth, which turns out to be a
  gateway into a magical parallel universe. As Milo passes through the
  tollbooth, the character moves from live action to animation, and his
  toy car transports him to the enchanted Kingdom of Wisdom and the
  cities of Digitopolis (numbers) and Dictionopolis (words).
Accompanied by Tock, a "watchdog" who actually has a large pocketwatch in his body, Milo has a series of adventures in places
  like the Mountains of Ignorance, the Doldrums, Dictionopolis,
  Digitopolis, and the Castle in the Air. Together they must rescue the
  Princesses Rhyme and Reason, who are being held captive in the Castle
  in the Air, and restore order to the Kingdom of Wisdom. The many
  eccentric characters they meet include the Humbug, the noisy Dr.
  Dischord, the Mathemagician, King Azaz, the Senses Taker, and Officer
  Short Shrift.


That is is! Thank you very much!
